# Oracle - Indexes

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I have been wondering how I can improve this Query in Oracle:

```
SELECT  FN_FORMAT_PEROPE(PEROPE) AS PERIODO,
        NVL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 1 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS NRO_EMITIDOS,
        NVL((SELECT SUM(DP.MONTO) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 1 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS MONTO_EMITIDO,
        NVL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 2 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS NRO_ABONADOS,
        NVL((SELECT SUM(DP.MONTO) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 2 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS MONTO_ABONADO,
        NVL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 3 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS NRO_RECHAZADOS,
        NVL((SELECT SUM(DP.MONTO) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 3 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS MONTO_RECHAZADO,
        NVL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 4 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS NRO_INDEBIDOS,
        NVL((SELECT SUM(DP.MONTO) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 4 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS MONTO_INDEBIDO,
        NVL((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PG_PAGO P /*INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 5*/ WHERE P.ESTADO = 5 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS NRO_RECUPEROS,
        NVL((SELECT SUM(DP.MONTO) FROM PG_PAGO P INNER JOIN PG_DETALLE_PAGO DP ON P.IDPAGO = DP.IDPAGO WHERE DP.ESTADO = 5 AND P.PEROPE = R.PEROPE),0) AS MONTO_RECUPERO
        FROM PG_RESOLUCIONES R ORDER BY R.PEROPE ASC;
```

Consider:

- **PG_PAGO** and **PG_DETALLE_PAGO** have about 35.000.000 records.
- I use indexes for both tables, but it doesn't work, because this query
  is too slow.

Thanks for  your help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the commenting out of the inner join in your query is a testing artefact, you could grab the results from the *_pago tables in one go using a pivoted query along the lines of this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT p.perope,
               dp.estado,
               dp.monto
        FROM pg_pago p
             INNER JOIN pg_detalle_pago dp ON p.idpago = dp.idpago
        WHERE  dp.estado IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
PIVOT (COUNT(*) AS nro,
       SUM(dp.monto) AS monto
       FOR estado IN (1 AS emitidos,
                      2 AS abonados,
                      3 AS rechazados,
                      4 AS indebidos,
                      5 AS recuperos));
```

N.B. untested. Also, this works in Oracle 11g and above.

Once you've got that set of results, it should be easy to join it back to your pg_resoluciones table and alias the columns as required.

Comment: I just tested in Oracle  11g and it works awesome! thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The key to solving your database performance is to query the tables once instead of ten times. Here is one way to achieve that (**caveat**: untested, may contain errors)

```
select  fn_format_perope(r.perope) as periodo
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 1 and then 1 else 0 end ) as nro_emitidos
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 1 and then dp.monto else 0 end ) as monto_emitido
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 2 and then 1 else 0 end ) as nro_abonados
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 2 and then dp.monto else 0 end ) as monto_abonado
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 3 and then 1 else 0 end ) as nro_rechazados
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 3 and then dp.monto else 0 end ) as monto_rechazado
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 4 and then 1 else 0 end ) as nro_indebidos
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 4 and then dp.monto else 0 end ) as monto_indebido
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 5 and then 1 else 0 end ) as nro_recupero
        , sum ( case when dp.estado = 5 and then dp.monto else 0 end ) as monto_recupero
from pg_resoluciones r 
     left outer join pg_pago p 
        on p.perope = r.perope
     left outer join pg_detalle_pago dp 
       on p.idpago = dp.idpago 
order by r.perope asc;
```

You need to use outer joins for PG_PAGO and PG_DETALLE_PAGO because it seems they may not have matching records (inferred from your use of `NVL()` in the scalar queries).

---

This version will work on any version of Oracle. The PIVOT version which @Boneist has written is more elegant, and that's probably the appproach you should take if you're on 11g or higher.